# ROBLOX LUA(u) Attempt to call a nil value on Database

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm trying to make a DB and I'm still in testing phrase, but it doesn't work.
Basically the error is, I want it so if I type: `ModuleScript:GetDB("salvage").Set("key", "value")`, it would return a value, but it doesn't due to an error.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Error:
[Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3DmHk.png)

Server Script:

```lua
local ModuleScript = require(game.ServerStorage.ModuleScript)

game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(p)
    p.Chatted:Connect(function(msg)
        if msg == "t" then
            print("lol")
            print(ModuleScript:GetDB("salvage"))
            ModuleScript:GetDB("salvage").Set("key", "value")
        end
    end)
end)
```

Module script:

```
--Variables
local dss = game:GetService("DataStoreService")

-- Tables
local greenwich = {}
local dbFunctions = {}

--Functions
function greenwich:GetDB(name)
    
    local db = dss:GetDataStore(name)
    local new = {}
    
    new.store = db
    
    coroutine.resume(coroutine.create(function()
        for k, v in ipairs(dbFunctions) do

            new[k] = function(...)

                local args = { ... }
                v(new.store, unpack(args))

            end

        end
    end))
    
    print(new.store.Name, name)
    
    return new
    
end

function dbFunctions:Set(store, key, value)
    print(value)
    return value
end

--Returning everything.
return greenwich
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ModuleScript:GetDB("salvage")` returns `new` which does not have a field `Set` so you cannot call `ModuleScript:GetDB("salvage").Set("key", "value)`

`Set` is a field of `dbFunctions`. You run a generic for loop over it using the `ipairs` iterator. `dbFunctions` is not a seqence, hence `ipairs` does not work for it. Use `pairs` instead.